# py2exe ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, pandas, exe, py2exe

I am trying to make an executable file for a python program. In the python program, I import pandas library. So, when I try to import pandas and apply py2exe.
I get:

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package from mf3.py file
>   line 213 in py2exe module.

My setup.py looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['program.py'])
```

Let me know if there is a fix to this

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229722/py2exe-fails-with-pandas-import)? I personally recomend cx_freeze over py2exe.

Comment: I cannot use cx_freeze as it requires MS Visual C++ building tools. I dont have administrative power with my work computer and cannot install what  I want

Comment: Make sure to use sys.setrecursionlimit(3000) as described in the previous comment.

Comment: Still the same error.