# py2exe consistently fails when importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe

I am trying to compile my code as an executable. After multiple fails I isolated the problem being pandas. Importing pandas results in a corrupted executable when compiling with py2exe. It compiles fine, i.e. I get no error when running my setup.py py2exe but running the executable results in a RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files.

I changed my setup.py after browsing through other questions. It currently looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

import py2exe

setup(console=['import_test.py'],
      options = {
         'py2exe': {
             'includes':['pandas'],
            'dll_excludes': ['MSVCP90.dll'],

            }
        }
      )
```

As for my import_test.py:

```
import pandas
print 'hello'
```

Did anyone experience this? Most questions relating to pandas & py2exe revolve around the missing dlls or the recursion limit exceeded, both issues which I have fixed already. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I'm looking for an answer using py2exe.

Comment: Looks related to [py2exe fails with pandas import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229722/py2exe-fails-with-pandas-import).

Comment: @Kanak OP already stated that they successfully adressed the recursion limit issue, so this is not a helpful link imo.

Comment: @SpghttCd Yeah yeah you are right. almost 4AM here.

Answer (score 0):

try this , this is awesome - https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/
to install - pip install auto-py-to-exe